# How to color a map, so that one color covers the maximum area.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, coloring

Given a graph $G$ where every node resembles a number. How would one color this graph, so that no two connected nodes have the same color and that one color has the maximum of area? Area is defined by the number inside the node.

[image]

For this example problem I found a solution of $22$. This is achieved by coloring the number 8, the lower 5, the highest 3, the upper right 4 and the remaining 2. I'd like to know if there is a good method for finding this number without using trial and error.

EDIT: You can use as many colors as you like, so the four color theorem does not apply here.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an algorithm?

Comment: or a way to get to the answer directly

Comment: Ah yeah- so a method to solve problems like this in general I take it you're looking for.

Comment: Is it implied that there is a limit to the number of colors allowed, e.g. like the $4$-color map problem?

Comment: This problem is NP hard to solve in general. To show why, we can very easily show that a solution of this implies a solution of the known NP-hard problem of finding the maximal independent set in a graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory). To show why, take any unweighted graph and set all the weights to $1$, then it is transformed to this problem.

Comment: @hardmath I initially had the same thought but I don't think limiting colours matters at all.

Comment: @Colm: The maximum independent set problem, although NP-hard in general, may be tractable for planar graphs with some restrictions.   I am posting from my phone and had difficulty pasting a link.

Comment: @hardmath yep I'd say there are many heuristics out there! But once I see something is NP hard it kind of knocks the enthusiasm out of my lungs because I know I'll never find a general solution, unless I win a million dollars i.e. 831240 euro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I worked out a solution to the example problem and a decent method to get there. Copy of the problem:

[image: The problem]]

First I decided that it wasn't needed to label all of them with the same color. There's is only one color we're actually interested in. So we can label every node with R (Red) or O (Other).

For the 8 we have two options: R or O. If we color it in with O it must mean that we would have to color the 4, the 2 or the 3 with R. Because if we were to cover them all with O, we would just lose the 8 points for no reason. So what is the maximum amount of points we can get by coloring the 4, 2 and 3? Seven of course (color the 4 and the 3). But 7 is less then 8 so you'd have to color 8. There are basically two options:

8: R, 4: O, 2: O, 3: O --> this results in a score of 8.

8: O, 4: R, 2: O, 3: R --> results in a score of 7 and you also make 3 other nodes (the 5, 2 and 3) O, so they can't contribute any points.

So I color the 8 Red. The 4, 2 and 3 must be any Other color.

No I can lift the 8, 4, 2 and 3 out of the graph. They have been colored in so they don't matter anymore. Now you could simplify the problem to this:

[simplified problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh49u.png)

You could go through the problem one more time but instead of looking at the 8, you can look at the lower 5. Again there are two options:

5: R, 2: O, 3: O, 2: O --> results in a score of 5.

5: O, 2: R, 3: O, 2: R --> results in a score of 4 and covers up 4 other nodes with O.

So I color the 5 red and the 2, 3 and 2 must be any Other color.

rince and repeat:

[More Simplified Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXTjB.png)

Take a look at the two's at the left.

Two options:

Lowest 2: R, higher 2: O --> results in a score of 2.

Lowest 2: 0, higher 2: R --> results in a score of 2 and you cover up the 4.

Take the Lowest 2. Simplify.

[Last Simplified Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2UKj.png)

From here I can see that, to take the maximum amount, I now need to take the 3 and the 4 to get the maximum in this graph. And at this point we're done. We have a total of: 8 + 5 + 2 + 4 + 3 = 22.

NOTE: This sudoku-ing of the graph doesn't always work (just like how not all beginning positions of a sudoko are solvable). I tried for example with the map of the United States: I got stuck. The 'algorithm' I used is still extremely cumbersome and takes a lot of time.